# Property placeholder in non-bean xml file

Tags: spring, property-placeholder

I have a abc.xml file which is not a spring-bean definition/context file in a Spring boot application. It is just a custom xml file that application needs.

The abc.xml has a password tag which needs an environment specific value and which cannot be hardcoded.

The password/value is available as an env property.

The process which reads the xml file using classpath:abc.xml should be able to read this env specific value as a placeholder replaced by Spring at runtime (or Spring can pre-load this file in memory with placeholder replaced).

The usual $ sign syntax such as ${env.propertyName} does not seem to work for xml files which are not context/bean definitions. How can we achieve this using Spring?

Thanks,
R